# 4 items - 25% each - with border & margin

Tags: html, css

So, I have searched through the internet and found problems that are a little alike but not exactly the same.

I have some sort of list that I want to show in a table form, and I want to use the whole width of the parent DIV it's in (so 100%).
I want to show 4 items per line, and used something like thias:

```
ul.li{
 list-style-type: none;
 float: left;
 display: box;
 border: 1px solid black;
 margin: 5px;
 padding: 10px;
 width: 25%
}
```

You don't have to be a mathematician to see what's wrong here: 25% * 4 is 100, but plus the border & the margin, the total is over 100. So the outcome is only 3 list items per line, and a lot under the total width of the parent div.

I've tried using a table instead of list items, it's a little easier to get the exact 100% width but it doesn't work for the rest of my page since it's not as flexible, it's just not what I need.

I could place the border inside the box, and that solves the border problem, but I need the margin (whitespace) between the boxes of my list items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1) `box-sizing: border-box;`, the width and height properties (and min/max properties) includes content, padding and border, **but not the margin**.
>
> 2) `width: calc(25% - 10px);` you use of `margin:5px` so must subtract `10px` for `(margin-left:5) and (margin-right:5)` of width:25% .

```
ul li{
 box-sizing: border-box;
 list-style-type: none;
 border: 1px solid black;
 float: left;
 margin: 5px;
 padding: 10px;
 width: calc(25% - 10px);
}
```

```css
ul li{
 box-sizing: border-box;
 list-style-type: none;
 border: 1px solid black;
 float: left;
 margin: 5px;
 padding: 10px;
 width: calc(25% - 10px);
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>7</li>
  <li>8</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: An answer without an explanation is not as useful. You should explain why `border-box` would fix the problem

Comment: @JuanMendes ok, i insert more detail.

Answer (score 0):

Try a calculated width: `width: calc(25% - 30px)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `flex` to solve it (I recommend you to read about it on [css-tricks.com](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)). What `flex` does is that it distrubute the items and take the margin in consideration. Basically you don't even need to use width but use `flex-basis`. Using `border-box` ([read about it](https://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/)) will calculate the padding + border you add to your `li` to the total width so it wont be, 25% + 20px but 25% including 20px, if that makes sense?

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/yva91z7e/2/)

```
<ul class="list">
  <li class="list__item">1</li>
  <li class="list__item">2</li>
  <li class="list__item">3</li>
  <li class="list__item">4</li>
</ul>

.list {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: lightcoral;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
}

.list__item {
  list-style-type: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  flex-basis: 25%
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
ul{
 list-style-type: none;
 margin: 5px;
 padding: 10px;
}
ul li{
 list-style-type: none;
 float: left;
 display: box;
 border: 1px solid black;
 margin: 5px;
 padding: 10px;
 width: 25%;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
</ul>
```